# ViewStub not getting hidden/deflated android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have following class and it's obeject which is inflated viewstub.

Statusbar-- class extends RelativeLayout

Statusbar b= (Statusbar)((ViewStub)findViewById(R.id.stub_one)).inflate();

Now I want to make this Statusbar visible/invisible or inflate/deflate depending on my need.
I tried b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE). But it didn't work.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
        findViewById(R.id.stub_one).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Please post the XML where you add the stub and the XML that you are inflating for the stub.